# Please help me with $\int 3x^2\sqrt{5x^3-3}dx$

Tags: integration, proof-writing, indefinite-integrals, self-learning, substitution

So, according to photomath the solution is:
[image]

however all I can do is:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abmLl.jpg):

[image]

Comment: Do you know what is $\int u^{1/2}\operatorname{du}$?  Evaluate that before re-replacing your $u$'s back with what they were in terms of $x$'s.  Recognize that $a\cdot \sqrt{a}$ is just another way of writing $a^{3/2}$

Comment: Is this homework? Feel free to override my edits,

Comment: Observe that $3x^2$ is the derivative of $x^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an evaluation with explained substitution:

$$\int 3x^2\sqrt{5x^3-3}dx$$

$u=5x^3-3\implies du=5\times 3x^2-0\implies \frac15 du=3x^2 dx$. We clearly see this part in the integral. Notice the (reverse) power rule:

$$\int \sqrt{5x^3-3}\boxed{3x^2dx}=\frac15 \int \sqrt u du=\frac15 \int u^\frac 12du=C+\frac15 \frac{1}{\frac12+1}u^{\frac 12+1}=\frac{2u^\frac32}{15}+C$$

Let’s substitute back $u=5x^3-3$:
$$\int 3x^2\sqrt{5x^3-3}dx =\frac{2u^\frac32}{15}+C= C+\frac{2(5x^3-3)^\frac32}{15}= C+\frac{2\sqrt{5x^3-3}(5x^3-3)}{15} $$

I hope this helps. Please remember to add more detail and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Thank you so much Tyma Gaidash

Comment: @CarlosNayi Thanks. Does this help or are there any questions?